# Radio buttons or colored box or checkbox for form entry

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap for my project.

I have build form and I want to have choices from the given colors, was searching for code and I could not find any that can make radio buttons to have colors.

Then I found this code

HTML:

```
<div class="foo blue"></div>
<div class="foo purple"></div>
<div class="foo wine"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  }
  
  .blue {
    background: #13b4ff;
  }
  
  .purple {
    background: #ab3fdd;
  }
  
  .wine {
    background: #ae163e;
  }
```

I am getting the colored boxes. But how to make the boxes selectable and to have value in them something like: value="red" so after clicking it to be sent to MySQL as "red"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  
}

.purple {
  background-color: #ab3fdd;
}

.blue
{
background-color: #13b4ff;
}

.wine
{
background-color: #ae163e;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .purple {
  background-color: #ab3fdd;
}

.container input:checked ~ .blue
{
background-color: #13b4ff;
}

.container input:checked ~ .wine
{
background-color: #ae163e;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="blue checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="purple checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="wine checkmark"></span>
</label>


</body>
</html>
```